# Android - Hide TextView with animation after CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How to hide `TextView` with animation after `CollapsingToolbarLayout` was collapsed?

TextView branchAddress, branchPhone and icon Search.

[image]

This is my xml code:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <ImageView />
            <Toolbar />
            <LinearLayout />
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>

    <NestedScrollView />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

[See full code here](https://www.codepile.net/pile/ADM0r08J)

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39073625/fading-the-whole-layout-as-scrolled-up-in-collapsing-bar-layout-android.  THough this describes fading out an entire `RelativeLayout`, the concept seems the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use addOnOffsetChangedListener to check your appbar is collapsed or not and change the visibility of textview.

Like Below:

```
appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(object : AppBarStateChangeListener() {
    override fun onStateChanged(
        appBarLayout: AppBarLayout?,
        state: State?
    ) {
        if(state == State.COLLAPSED){
            text = View.GONE
        }else if(state == State.EXPANDED){
            text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but class `AppBarStateChangeListener` is not found.

Comment: Is it here [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33891727/5187940)?

Comment: I want when scroll AppBar to hide, show TextViiew, it has effect like scale, alpha. How archive that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues you need to fix:

- Defining a transparent color in `app:contentScrim` attribute: This should be an opaque color instead as it wraps the `ImageView` and the text using the `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` behavior. I used an arbitrary color for this.
- Missing `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"` in the `LinearLayout` of the couple of textViews that you want to hide.

Also you need to move the `LinearLayout` of the couple of textView's to be below the `MaterialToolbar`, as both has different collapsing behaviors.

Applying those changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".presentation.common.view.Demo2HomeFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent">

            <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgHeaderBackground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="192dp"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:foreground="@drawable/img_header_background_overlay"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ImageviewRoundedBottom48dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtBranchAddress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="{branch.address}"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtBranchPhone"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="{branch.phone}"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?attr/actionBarItemBackground"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="56dp"
                android:paddingStart="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="8dp"
                android:paddingEnd="16dp"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgBranchLogo"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:scaleType="fitStart"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/abc_vector_test" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thank for your support. If i use color for `app:contentScrim`, when AppBar collapsed, I want to Image show still.